# Change function from f(x) to g(y)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

This might be very basic for some people here, but I'm a design student who's come across a mathematical question I can not solve with my basic maths skills.

I have the formala:
$f(x) = .03(x-18)^3+60$

How do I change this to become
$g(y)$ = ????

Thank you in advance!

PS: Sorry if this is not the right place to ask such questions. Also my apologies for the lack of decent formatting, I'm not familiar with the LaTeX format.

Comment: I'm guessing y=f(x)?

Comment: Are you trying to find the inverse of f(x)?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with the exact terminology. I wanted to make y = f(x) in to x = g(y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a gander at it:

I am assuming that $y=f(x)$

$$y=0.03*(x-18)^3+60 = \frac3{100}*(x-18)^3+60$$

- Pass the "$60$" to the left-hand side.

$$y-60 = \frac3{100}*(x-18)^3$$

- divide both sides by "$\frac3{100}$": $\frac1{(\frac3{100})}$ = $\frac{100}{3}$

$$\frac{100}{3}*(y-60) = (x-18)^3$$

- Take the cube root of both sides (raise both sides to the $\frac13$ power).

$$\left(\frac{100}{3}*(y-60)\right)^{1/3} = (x-18)$$

- Pass the "$18$" to the left-hand side.

$$\left(\frac{100}{3}*(y-60)\right)^{1/3} + 18 = x$$

There you go! Solution for $x$ in terms of $y$! It's fairly simple to do, $x$ occurs in only one place.

Note, it's not linear algebra, it's algebra/precalculus.

Answer (score 0):

You mean to take the inverse.
write your equation as

$$y=0.03(x-18)^3 +60$$
then 
$$y-60=0.03(x-18)^3$$
$$\frac{y-60}{0.03}=(x-18)^3$$
$$\sqrt[3]{\frac{y-60}{0.03}}=x-18$$
$$\sqrt[3]{\frac{y-60}{0.03}}+18=x$$

so

$$g(y)=\sqrt[3]{\frac{y-60}{0.03}}+18$$

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I completely understand your question, but this may be what you mean:

Let $y = f(x)$ meaning that we plug in an $x$ value to the right hand side, and get out a $y$ value. I believe you're looking to be able to plug in a $y$ value and get an $x$ value out. So we have $y = 0.3(x-18)^3 + 60$ and we can solve this equation for $x$ using some algebra, which will make it a function of $y$ :

\begin{align*}
y &= 0.3(x - 18)^3 + 60\\
y-60 &= 0.3(x - 18)^3
\end{align*}

This should get you started. Once you have this solved this for $x$, we can think of $x$ as a function of $y$ by calling $x = g(y)$.